# How do I use a SRFI inside a module in Chicken Scheme?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

The following file gives an error when it is compiled with `csc`.

```
(module
 monoid *
 (import chicken scheme)
 (use srfi-9)
 (define-record-type a0 (a0) a0?))
```

The error is:

```
Syntax error (import): cannot import from undefined module
    srfi-9
    Expansion history:
    ...
```

I followed an example in ["The CHICKEN User's Manual/Supported language/Modules/Examples of using modules"](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Modules#examples-of-using-modules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some smaller SRFIs are part of the `chicken` module. You can just remove the `(use srfi-9)` line.

I know that this is somewhat confusing, but if you read it carefully, the manual *doesn't* state that there is a module for it (and indeed, there isn't). This too has been made a bit saner in the upcoming CHICKEN 5. There, srfi-9 is a clean, separate module, and your example program works as-is on CHICKEN 5.